# Vendor.bundle file load slowly with angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, gzip, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 project, building by angular-cli.
After I run the `"npm build --prod"` command the dist folder looks like:

[image: dist folder content]

My web.config include gzip definitions like this:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
     <httpCompression>
        <dynamicTypes>
          <clear />
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
          <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
          <clear />
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
          <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
        </staticTypes>
      </httpCompression>
```

And the request headers including the gzip `Content-Encoding` and `Accept-Encoding`:

[image: request Headers]

I'm using Azure web app to host my website.

When I'm loading the site in chrome (for example) it's takes a lot of time,
the problematic file is the vendor.bundle - even though it's size is very small, like a picture (515KB) the loading takes 50sec!! when the image with same size loaded at 2sec.

this is the Network section in chrome dev tool:

[image: chrome network]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with angular 6 on Azure, did you figure this out?